# Certificate error during mail send

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Starting from few days ago my send mail java agent show this error:

```
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: No trusted certificate found
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1462)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1260)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:312)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Restarting HTTP works again. Intermittently error returns.
I tried also [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21588966) without success, following this steps:

1. downloaded locally `cacerts` file from domino server (from `jvm/lib/securty` folder)
2. downloaded `.cer` certificate from SMTP provider
3. Run the batch file `IKEYMAN.exe`
4. added the certificate
5. replaced `cacerts` into server
6. restarted HTTP

The certificate has been also added into Domino `keyring` file.
What could be the problem?
Why restarting HTTP returns to work for a while?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ssl certificate for your mail server has expired or someone has updated to a new certificate. So maybe you should contact your mail server supplier to get new certificate and then import it again.

Comment: Certificate is valid, isn't expired

Comment: What version of Domino and what fix pack?

Comment: 8.5.3 FP4 on Linux